# Symfony3 Why variable "label" from form.vars is empty

Tags: forms, symfony, variables, twig

I would like to have access to variable "label" in

```
form.postalCode.vars.label
```

I have form object: "form" and I made dump in twig of:

```
{{ dump(form.postalCode.vars) }}
```

This is result:

```
array:24 [▼
  "value" => ""
  "attr" => array:1 [▶]
  "form" => FormView {#771 ▶}
  "id" => "appbundle_test_name"
  "name" => "name"
  "full_name" => "appbundle_test[name]"
  "disabled" => false
  "label" => null
  "label_format" => null
  "multipart" => false
  "block_prefixes" => array:3 [▶]
  "unique_block_prefix" => "_appbundle_test_name"
  "translation_domain" => null
  "cache_key" => "_appbundle_test_name_text"
  "errors" => FormErrorIterator {#765 ▶}
  "valid" => true
  "data" => null
  "required" => true
  "size" => null
  "label_attr" => []
  "compound" => false
  "method" => "POST"
  "action" => ""
  "submitted" => false
]
```

Based on this documentation: https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/reference/forms/twig_reference.html#twig-reference-form-variables
Using "label" variable I should get access to title of label. My question is why this variable is empty. I checked each of my field from my form and each label of this field is empty...
But when I generate label using form_label -> label is generated without any problems.

Comment: Show us the code of the FormType, which loads this form. Then its possible to answer this question.

In my opinion, you did not set the label in the FormType.

Comment: There's your answer: you did not set the label thus `vars.label` is empty and auto-generated (ad hoc) inside the label block, eg.: `{{ vars.label ?: generate(vars.name) }}`

Answer (score 1):

I think that you need to add a label to your `postalCode` field first in your form builder, something like this

```php
    $builder = $this->add('postalCode', TextType::class, ['label' => 'Post code']);
```